# Is there a way to always display the hint in a DropDownButton?

Tags: flutter

For example, in a TextField it is possible to set an InputDecoration with a label text, that shows in the center of the TextField when there is no user input, and then shows above the user's input text afterward.

With a DropDownButton I can only seem to get the hint text to display before the user makes a selection, and then it disappears and only displays the user's selection. Is there a way to mimic the TextField's behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve that using `DropDownButtonFormField` widget instead of `DropDownButton`. `DropDownButtonFormField` has `decoration` property which lets you use `labelText` which goes over the top of the field after selecting an item from the list. Sample working code below:

```
return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'select option'
      ),

      value: selected,
      items: ["A", "B", "C"]
          .map((label) => DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(label),
                value: label,
              ))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() => selected = value);
      },
    );
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Hope this answers your question.